# How do I calculate a weighted average purchase date?

Tags: arithmetic

A farmer bought 100 kg of seed on the following dates:

```
20 kg on 13-may-2007 (20%)
30 kg on 4-oct-2007  (30%)
50 kg on 31-jul-2008 (50%)
```

How do I calculate the weighted average purchase date? I don't want weighted average age because that changes daily. I'm thinking of a specific point in time.
The total days between first and last purchase is 445 days.

Comment: If you have the age for some day $d$, $a(d)$, find $d$ such that $a(d) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you take 13-may-2007 as day zero, he bought 30 kg on day 144 and 50 kg on day 445.  How many kg-days is that?  Then divide by 100 and go that many days after 13-may.